# How do I prevent the currency from switching to local currency in Bluesnap BuyNow link?

Tags: bluesnap

When I enter the buy now link the currency is set according to my location, I want to force the currency to always be in USD.
How do I prevent the currency from switching to local currency in Bluesnap BuyNow link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BuyNow URL parameter **currency** to force the page to open on a specific currency, such as USD. For instance, a BuyNow 2 link such as this:

```
https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/buynow/checkout?sku2331065=1&storeid=21617
```

will open in your local currency. But this BuyNow2 link:

```
https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/buynow/checkout?sku2331065=1&storeid=21617&currency=USD
```

will always open in USD currency.